# function calls in pine return unexpected value

Tags: pine-script

I am new to tradingview and I found a script I am trying to rebuild in Octave, but I don't get exactly the same results. After some painful debugging in trading view I found out, that the following lines show different results than what I expected:

```
I2 = I1 - jQ
Q2 = Q1 + jI

// computePart(src) 
//     => 0.2 * src + 0.8 * nz(src[1])
I2 := computePart(I2)
Q2 := computePart(Q2) 
// debug variables
debugRe = 0.2 * I2 + 0.8 * nz(I2[1])
debugIm = 0.2 * Q2 + 0.8 * nz(Q2[1])
```

debugRe != I2 and debugIm !=Q2 , even though the calculation of the debug variables do exactly the same as the function defines? Do I have some misunderstanding, how function calls work in pine script or should those value be the same?

I can manually calculate the values of I2 and Q2, by these lines:

```
debugRe = 0.2*(I1 - jQ) + 0.8*(I1[1] - jQ[1])
debugIm = 0.2*(Q1 + jI) + 0.8*(Q1[1] + jI[1])
```

That's why I have the feeling, that the first assignments for I2 and Q2 seem like symbolic assignments.

I would be very happy about a tip / help into the right direction, maybe just a reference to understand it better would be enough.

Thank you,

Seb

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet doesn't compile and doesn't contain dependencies, so can't really troubleshoot it. One thing's for sure, your debugging assignments are NOT equivalent to the ones where you are calling the function. For them to be equivalent, would need:

```
I2 := 0.2 * I2 + 0.8 * nz(I2[1])
Q2 := 0.2 * Q2 + 0.8 * nz(Q2[1])
```

Perhaps this may help you visualize the impact of initialization on every bar (without using the `var` keyword, as with variable `a`), and that of initializing only on the first bar (variables `b` and `c`).

`f_c()` also shows how, when initializing on the first bar only, the variable's value is then automatically propagated bar to bar and you don't need the `[1]` operator to refer to it's previous value:

```
//@version=4
study("v2")
a = 100.
var b = 100.
var c = 100.
f_(_src) => nz(_src[1]) + 10
f_c(_src) => _src + 10
a := f_(a)
b := f_(b)
c := f_c(c)
plot(a, "a", color.aqua, 5, transp = 60)
plot(b, "b", color.fuchsia)
plot(c, "c")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think this guides me in the right direction, where I still have problems to understand how pine script works. I added these lines to your code:


`...your code...
f_c(_src) => _src + 10
d=0.
d:=nz(a[1]) + 10
plot(d, "d")
...your code...
`

d has the value 120, when a has the value 110, even though I do the same calculation just not in a  function. Could you explain how this works / what is the principle behind?
I would expect that a and d have the same value. 
Thanks a lot for your help, Seb